# Looping over objects in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, d3.js

I am fairly new to coding. I did search the forum but could not find an answer to the problem I am trying to solve. I wrote a basic node app. It will be used to track the efficacy of an afterschool fitness program for a public school system. The students answer a set of questions after each visit to the program. The teachers look at the data to assess the program. The data is stored in a MongoDB collection:

```
 var visitSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userid: String,
    date: String,
    activitylist: String,
    presession: String,
    health: String,
    bestpart: String,
    worstpart: String,
    postsession: String,
    approved: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
 });
```

I am using d3 to try show some graphs that will assist the teachers in their analysis. This would include reporting on metrics associated some of the items in the array. As an example, how many times did the students participate in one of the 4 activities listed, to see if one is not being leveraged. Another would be the presession, postsession and health items, as these are derived from  radio inputs and are one of four options. 
I was successful in pulling the mongoDB data into the console.

Here are some example visits as they appear there:

```
    [{"_id":"5a56c70d4035a90aafbe99f2","date":"Wed Jan 10 2018 20:08:13 GMT-0600 (CST)","userid":"5a54270477a5d3ff63803879","activitylist":"swimming","presession":"ok","bestpart":"water","worstpart":"splashing","postsession":"good","__v":0,"approved":true},{"_id":"5a66ab728f12a65cadefb117","date":"Mon Jan 22 2018 21:26:42 GMT-0600 (CST)","userid":"5a54270477a5d3ff63803879","activitylist":"yoga","presession":"good","health":"good","bestpart":"hi","worstpart":"there","postsession":"verygood","__v":0,"approved":true},{"_id":"5a6d0b815e8791217f50948a","date":"Sat Jan 27 2018 17:30:09 GMT-0600 (CST)","userid":"5a67ee7d0f7d0a0b7fb1ae2f","presession":"good","health":"verygood","bestpart":"good","worstpart":"hag","postsession":"good","__v":0,"approved":false},{"_id":"5a6d0b905e8791217f50948b","date":"Sat Jan 27 2018 17:30:24 GMT-0600 (CST)","userid":"5a67ee7d0f7d0a0b7fb1ae2f","presession":"great","health":"good","bestpart":"hi","worstpart":"hello","postsession":"verygood","__v":0,"approved":false},{"_id":"5a6d0d80f6d66c225d103783","date":"Sat Jan 27 2018 17:38:40 GMT-0600 (CST)","userid":"5a67ee980f7d0a0b7fb1ae30","activitylist":"basketball","presession":"great","health":"verygood","bestpart":"hi","worstpart":"hello","postsession":"verygood","__v":0,"approved":false},{"_id":"5a6fe540695e704dd125355a","date":"Mon Jan 29 2018 21:23:44 GMT-0600 (CST)","userid":"5a67ee980f7d0a0b7fb1ae30","activitylist":"basketball","presession":"great","health":"good","bestpart":"bas","worstpart":"nas","postsession":"verygood","__v":0,"approved":false}]
```

I was also successful in getting the data to render in the d3 charts. Here is where I am stuck. Right now, I am using the following code parse the data and populate the charts. The example below is for the activitylist item. It goes over the data and counts the number of each activity in the data:

```
function constructData(visitData) {
    let data = [{ label: "basketball", value: 0 }, { label: "swimming", value: 0 }, { label: "yoga", value: 0 }]
    visitData.forEach(function(visit) {
        console.log(visit.activitylist)

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i])
            //if (visit.activitylist in data[i])
            if (visit.activitylist == data[i].label) { data[i].value++ }
        }



    })

    //change(data);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

So that works for parsing the data, but I would have to do something similar for every item in the collection I wanted to report on. I was looking for a more global function, into which I could pass the item I was interested (activitylist, presession, etc.) or just iterate over each (or a selction of) items in the collection. I have been playing with those code below, but have yet to make it work. The array is just a simple one so I could test.

```
 var data = [{
    'pear': 1,
    'apple': 2
 }, {
    'pear': 5,
    'mango': 10
 }, {
    'pear': 3,
    'apple': 5,
 }]

 let final = []
 data.forEach((visit) => {
    for (var key in visit) {
        if (visit.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //console.log(visit[key], key)
            final.forEach((f) => {
                console.log(f)
                if (f[key]) {
                    f[key]++
                        return;
                }

            })
            console.log(key)
            let obj = {}
            obj[key] = 0;
            final.push(obj)
        }

    }

 })
 console.log(final)
```

So any suggestions on a function like the one above that could loop through the data to check each item, or the ones I specify, in the array would be greatly appreciated. As I stated I am fairly new to this so I apologize if my wording was not entirely clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are conflicted on how to best iterate over an objects properties. You have a lot of options, and if you'd like to use a loop you could do something like a for-in:

```
var visitSchema = {
  userid: 'String1',
  date: 'String2',
  activitylist: 'String3',
  presession: 'String4',
  health: 'String5',
  bestpart: 'String6',
  worstpart: 'String7',
  postsession: 'String8',
  approved: {
      type: true,
      default: false
  }
}

for (var x in visitSchema) {
  console.log(x + ' - ' + visitSchema[x]);
}
```

While there's certainly nothing *wrong* with iterating over objects and arrays with loops, more modern (and slick) way of handling this task involves is by chaining array methods together (the big three being map, filter and reduce). There's a great article about just that [here](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/05/04/functional-programming-in-javascript-map-filter-reduce/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this way to parse the data without using so much of looping.

```
const temp = []; 
for (const d in this.data) {
        if (this.data[d]) {
          temp.push({
            name: d,
            value: this.data[d],
          });
        }
}
```